# I get Bad file descriptor error using pipes

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent

I get **Bad file descriptor error** in my program, where my parent process reads two double values from two .txt files (the length of the files are same), if the absolute value of the first number - the second number is greater than 2, the parent process sends it to pid3 child process, else it sends to pid2 child process.

I think, that I have problem with the pipes.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>  
#include <sys/unistd.h>  
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

double atlag = 0;

double absz(double, double);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    FILE* be1;
    FILE* be2;
    // FILE* kiugro;
    // FILE* atlag;

    pid_t pid2, pid3;
    double x1, x2;
    int  p1[2], p2[2];

    be1 = fopen("be1.txt", "r");
    be2 = fopen("be2.txt", "r");

    if(pipe(p2) < 0)
    {
        syserr("pipe");
    }

    if(pipe(p1) < 0)
    {
        syserr("pipe");
    }

    if((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        syserr("fork");
    }

    if((pid3 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        syserr("fork");
    }

    if(pid2 == 0)
    {
        if(close(p1[1]) < 0)
        {
            syserr("close");
        }

        double temp;

        while(read(p1[0], &temp, sizeof(double)) == sizeof(double))
        {
            if(isnan(temp))
            {
                fclose(be2);
                break;
            }

            printf("a kulonbseg nkiugro: %lf\n", temp);
        }

        if(close(p1[0]) < 0)
        {
            syserr("close");
        }
    }

    if(pid3 == 0)
    {
        if(close(p2[1]) < 0)
        {
            syserr("close");
        }

        double temp;

        while(read(p2[0], &temp, sizeof(double)) == sizeof(double))
        {
            if(isnan(temp))
            {
                fclose(be1);
                break;
            }
            printf("a kulonbseg kiugro: %lf\n", temp);
        }

        if(close(p2[0]) < 0)
        {
            syserr("close");
        }
    }

    //parent process

    if(close(p2[0]) < 0)
    {
        syserr("close");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        if((fscanf(be1, "%lf", &x1) != EOF) && (fscanf(be2, "%lf", &x2) != EOF))
        {
            usleep(200);
            double temp = absz(x1, x2);

            if(temp > 2)
            {
                write(p2[1], &temp, sizeof(double));
            }
            else
            {
                write(p1[1], &temp, sizeof(double));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            double temp = NAN;

            write(p2[1], &temp, sizeof(double));
            write(p1[1], &temp, sizeof(double));

            break;
        }
    }

    if(close(p1[1]) < 0)
    {
        syserr("close");
    }

    if(close(p2[1]) < 0)
    {
        syserr("close");
    }

    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid3, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}

double absz(double x1, double x2)
{
    if((x1 - x2) >= 0)
    {
        return x1 - x2;
    }
    else
    {
        return (x1 - x2) * (-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the 'bad file descriptor' error?  Which line(s)?  How many times?  Note that after the two calls to `fork()`, you have four (4) processes running.

Comment: The code after `//parent process` is run in the children too, since the child code never exits.

Comment: And how do I exit from child processes, I tought, that I have 3 processes: pid2, pid3 and parent process.

Comment: Using exit(int), where int should be a value between 0-255.

Comment: If you print a message before you `close(p2[0])` you will see that it is printed 4 times. indicating that you have 4 processes running within that program's context.

Comment: And how could I change my code to have only 3 processes? (parent process and and pid2, pid3)

Comment: Use `if (pid2 != 0 && (pid3 == fork()) < 0)` to only have the parent fork twice.